# React-Native setup faults

Tags: android, react-native

I'm experiencing multiple issues that are hindering me from even getting started with React:

First

> react-native@0.40.0 requires a peer of react@15.4.0-rc.4 but none was installed

is returned when I run `react-native init "projectname"`

Can't find any solution to that so I move on:

```
react-native start
```

returns

> Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\me\.babel.json'

when I try to run the app:

```
react-native run-android
```

The app in my device returns:

> Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

as far as I know, I have followed the docs in every detail. I tried reinstalling Node etc. But I have no idea what this is all about.

Thanks in advance if anyone can help with this!

EDIT: I'm on Windows 7

**UPDATE**

npm now runs without fault.

> Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\me.babel.json'

is resolved by reinstalling for a third time.

However:

> Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

is still returned when the app is run on my device.

Answer (score 0):

The line "react-native@0.40.0 requires a peer of react@~15.4.0-rc.4 but none was installed." is just a WARN, it's probably not the source of your problems.

There are quite a few things you need to do to get started on the android side of things before your app will run. Have you done steps 1 through 4 here:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#1-download-and-install-android-studio

What's in the me.babel.json file?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm on Windows 7. But yes, I've followed all the steps. Got the correct SDK tools, Android Environment variable, Node, The React Native CLI etc.. The babel.json contains a load of this: http://pastebin.com/76XwtcuE

Answer (score 0):

> Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly

This error is because `react-native start` failed.

I have no idea what the babel.json file is supposed to be used but I would remove it and try again.

Comment: I tried that. When I run "react-native start" after that, it's being recreated in the same location and returns the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced the error *Could not get BatchedBridge, make sure your bundle is packaged correctly* after following the [React Native Getting Started](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) guide for Windows (Windows 7 x64) and Android. Towards the end of the output of `react-native run-android`, I saw an error message complaining about the adb command beeing missing.

**I solved this by adding**

```
C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools
```

**to my user's PATH environment variable.**

After this, the error *Could not get BatchedBridge* also went away.

I also see *Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, open 'C:\Users\Username.babel.json'* in the React Packager output most of the time (sometimes twice), but it looks like it can just be ignored.